# Get Mechanical Turk task input data (e.g. example image url) from Boto API

Tags: python, boto, mechanicalturk

When retreiving results from a Mechanical Turk assignment via the `boto` API, how can I see the input data from the CSV that is provided before creating a new batch?

The only way I've been able to find it (other than from the original CSV file) is from the batch results CSV availabe from from the MTurk web dashboard.

Neither [`get_assignment()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/mturk.html#MTurk.Client.get_assignment) nor [`get_hit()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/mturk.html#MTurk.Client.get_hit) seem to include this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to access this information through the API, though somewhat indirectly.

I should note that I am working with a bounding box task, where the required input is an image URL per question.

When calling `get_hit()`, the response in includes a `Question` field that contains the XML layout of the question shown to the worker. Some of the input data, which includes the image URL I was looking for, is available by parsing in this XML data.

I used BeautifulSoup to parse the XML:

```
# Get the assignment
assignment = client.get_assignment(AssignmentId=assignment_id)
# Load the XML for the question, aka task
question_soup = BeautifulSoup(assignment['HIT']['Question'], 'lxml')
task_input = question_soup.find('crowd-bounding-box')
# Extract the image src
image_url = task_input['src']
```